# wilcox.test in R: W stat and p value seem to disagree

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a data set with two groups of 13 people (`condition`: `sim` and `con`), who get a score for a task (`value`). They perform a number of tasks at various time points, which form columns `Task` and `timepoint`, but for the example below I have just selected a single task and timepoint for simplicity.

I want to formally compare if the distributions are different: they are not normally distributed, and on quick inspection of the raw data and on a plot they are markedly different (not 'science' I know). I am using `wilcox.test` as a Mann-Whitney U in R.

The problem I am having is the first time I run the test, I try to run it on the tibble, with the condition as the grouping factor, and the W/U value seem to 'disagree' - I've worked though below.

My question is:
1)Clearly there is something wrong with my formula in the first example, but I have tried reading the help and tinkering with `subset`, but to no avail, so shere have I gone wrong in the first attempt? (ideally I would like to run this a number of times for different Tasks, the missing column, and I don't want to manual have to pull out a vector for each condition for each Task.
2)Which W/U is correct? I would assume it the lower value (3, see below), as it 'agrees' with the p value.

Many thanks in advance.

I'm using R version 3.3.2, in R Studio, and have loaded the `tidy verse` package.

```
# A tibble: 26 x 2
 condition value
  <fctr>           <int>
 1       sim              99
 2       sim             100
 3       con             242
 4       con             255
 5       con             194
 6       sim             135
 7       con             504
 8       sim             131
 9       sim             115
10       sim             159
# ... with 16 more rows
```

If I run a Mann-Whitney U test on the data:

```
wilcox.test(value ~ condition, data = q)
```

I get the follow result:

```
Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  value by condition
W = 165, p-value = 3.445e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

However, the U/W value seemed high (above the [critical value](http://ocw.umb.edu/psychology/psych-270/other-materials/RelativeResourceManager.pdf) on the tables when I checked manually) yet the p value would lead me to reject the null hypothesis. So I separated the tibble into two purely numeric vectors (one for each condition) and repeated the test:

```
qsim <- q$value[q$condition == "sim"]
> qsim
[1]  99 100 135 131 115 159 105  77 178 131 120 175 191 130

qcon <- q$value[q$condition == "con"]
> qcon
[1] 242 255 194 504 545 344 194 198 208 173 349 280

wilcox.test(qsim, qcon)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  qsim and qcon
W = 3, p-value = 3.445e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

The p-value is the same, but the U/W value is lower (and far more in keeping with what I would expect by visually comparing the vectors, let alone plotting them).

Comment: Oh, I did it by hand (I know) to confirm, and indeed 3 is correct for the U/W value. I know I have clearly made an error, but I can't identify it: any help much appreciated as it will save my sanity!

Comment: **Hint**: The lengths of `qsim` and `qcon` are $14$ and $12$. Have you noticed that $165+3=168=14\times 12$? Here's another hint: when you run a t-test or z-test of a difference between two means, there are two orders in which you can subtract the means.  One leads to a test statistic of (say) $Z$ while the other leads to a statistic of $-Z$. Although these values are different, how will their two-tailed p-values compare?

Comment: @whuber Many thanks for the hints, they really helped me get it. I hadn't noticed that, even though I get U1+U2=n1*n2, I had just assumed that the result would automatically pick the lower of the Us to present. Thanks for taking the time, P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is answered here:  [Difference between wilcox.test using COMMA vs TILDE SIGN (and the interpretation of the resulting W-statistic)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234798/difference-between-wilcox-test-using-comma-vs-tilde-sign-and-the-interpretation) .

The difference in W statistic is simply the order in which you have e.g. `con` and `sim` in `wilcox.test(sim, con)`, or the order of the factors in the forumula.