# Wilcoxon or Mann Whitney

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am studying when using non-parametric statistical hypothesis test, I have an example says that in a Boxing arena we pick a sample of 20 people. We ask them how much time they watch boxing in TV in a week and we want compare if we have differences between people younger than 40 and older than forty. What test would be better? I think it is Mann Whitney, but in my book, it says we work with two samples and in this case we only work with one. could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the W statistic output by wilcox.test() in R the same as the U statistic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79843/is-the-w-statistic-output-by-wilcox-test-in-r-the-same-as-the-u-statistic)

Comment: You actually do have two samples, one for people younger than 40 and one for people older than 40.

Comment: then, should I use Mann Whitney? Other option would be to use ANOVA, what do you think? Thanks